# Run time Error '1004' using .Formula

Tags: excel

I'm building an master excel file that is designed to gather data from lots of other excel files that are stored in the business Dropbox files and place them in the 2nd sheet of the master file.  I built a original version on my local computer and that worked perfectly (the path3 variable) but once I tried to convert it based on a changing file path (because each user will have a different path from their PC) I am getting the run time error. The formula defined by path2 is what I have been trying to use but even though the variable seems to be holding the right value (I tested it by having it write out the values) it doesn't seem to be able to move the data, throwing the above error and highlighting the "rngdest.Formula = Chr(61) & path2" line. I really don't have any idea what is causing this and I have spent several days trying different approaches but to no avail so any ideas, solutions or links to already solved (I have spent a long time searching but haven't found anything) would be very much appreciated. 
I've included the whole of the code for completeness, I think I've removed most of the redundant code that I left in but there may be some still left. If you need any clarifications on the code please let me know. Thanks for any potential help

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim counter As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim a As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim Names() As String
Dim Fix1() As String
Dim path3 As String
Dim path2 As String
Dim SheetName As String
Dim c As Range
Dim found As Range
Dim BookName As String
Dim var1 As String
Dim rngdest As Range
Dim rngsource As Range
Dim cell As String
Dim adjust As Integer
Dim adjust2 As Integer
Dim rngname As Range
Dim colNo As Integer
Dim fin As String
Dim fin2 As String
Dim fin3 As String
Dim comp As String
Dim teststring As String

Dim currentWb2 As Workbook
Set currentWb2 = ThisWorkbook
MsgBox "Excel will now update the sheet, please be patient as this can take             a few minutes. You will be notified once it is complete"

ReDim Fix1(1 To 4)
Fix1(1) = "A-F"
Fix1(2) = "G-L"
Fix1(3) = "M-R"
Fix1(4) = "S-Z"
counter = 0
With ActiveSheet
i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
ReDim Names(1 To i, 1 To 4)
With ActiveSheet
For k = 1 To 4
For a = 2 To i

Names(a, k) = Cells(a, k).Value

Next a
Next k

End With
SheetName = "Analysis"
BookName = "Outcomes Final.xlsm"

For p = 1 To 4

fin2 = Split(Cells(, p).Address, "$")(1)
With ActiveSheet
l = .Cells(.Rows.Count, fin2).End(xlUp).Row
End With


For z = 1 To l
counter = counter + 1
fin = Split(Cells(, counter).Address, "$")(1)


currentWb2.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("" & fin & "1") = Names(z, p)

For y = 1 To 34


adjust = y + 1

cell = "$B$" & y & ""

If z = 1 Then
Else
teststring = GetPath()
teststring = teststring & "\Clients\"
path3 = "'C:\Users\Lewis\Documents\Outcomes\Floating Support\Clients\" &     Fix1(p) & "\" & Names(z, p) & "\[Outcomes Final.xlsm]Analysis'!" & cell & ""
path2 = teststring & Fix1(p) & "\" & Names(z, p) & "\Outcomes\[Outcomes Final.xlsm]Analysis'!" & cell & ""

End If

Set rngdest = currentWb2.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("" & fin & "" & adjust & "")

Set rngsource = Range("B" & y & "")

rngdest.Formula = Chr(61) & path2
Next y
Next z
Next p
currentWb2.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
currentWb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D35").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
For j = 1 To counter
fin3 = Split(Cells(, j).Address, "$")(1)

If currentWb2.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("" & fin3 & "35") = "1" Then

With currentWb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D35")
comp = currentWb2.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("" & fin3 & "1")

Set c = .Find(comp, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not c Is Nothing Then

c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3


End If
End With
End If
Next j
MsgBox "The update is now complete, please click on sheet 2 to view the     data. All clients in red have not been properly completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you change the line to `rngdest.Formula = Chr(39) & Chr(61) & path2` then check the worksheet cell and try to remove the `'`, does it become a valid formula?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it then gives the standard error saying 'We found a problem with this formula'.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. VBA is not a way to put a bad formula into a cell. Figure out what you are doing wrong with that formula on the worksheet and then transfer the fix to the VBA.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not convinced I completely understand the difference between the original formula and the one I have now but I played around with putting apostrophe in at different points of the file path build and have somehow managed to get it to work. Thanks a lot for your time